# Using Google Sheets API to write to a sheet in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-sheets-api

I am trying to update a sheet by writing some data into it. I am not able to understand how to create a `GTLRSheets_ValueRange`  object to send in the initialise method for the `GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate`

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: action, nil];
GTLRSheets_ValueRange *value;
NSMutableDictionary *datum = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: @{ @"values": data }];
value.JSON = datum;
GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate *query2 = [GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate queryWithObject:value spreadsheetId:spreadsheetId range:@"Sheet1!D3"];
```

Here I am creating a Mutable Dictionary datum with a single string as I want to update only a single cell. It fails to assign it to value.

I get a null object after the assignment.

Is this the right way to write data to a sheet, if yes what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a method in the GTLRObject definition from which GTLRSheets_ValueRange derives called objectWithJSON.

Now using this my code works.

Before

```
value.JSON = datum;
```

Now

```
value = [GTLRSheets_ValueRange objectWithJSON:datum];
```